# How do we redirect logs for spring using appenders

Tags: spring, log4j

I want to redirect spring logs and logs generated from log4j to a separate file using appenders.

Is the below approach correct? Also, How can I redirect logs from log4j to a different file. Please advice.

```
<!-- Logger for Spring 
<category name="org.springframework">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="Spring"/>
 </category>  
     -->

 <appender name="Spring" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
     <param name="File" value="./logs/spring.log"/>
     <param name="Append" value="false"/>
     <param name="BufferedIO" value="true"/>
     <param name="DatePattern" value="-yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>

     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%x [%d{MMM dd, yyyy 
       HH:mm:ss}] [%t] %-5p [%c] - %m%n"/>
     </layout>

    </appender>
```

Comment: above looks like ok, do yo get any errors?

Comment: Thank u for the reply. Still need to test this out, I was not sure of the approach .Also, How can I separate the log4j logs to a different file on similar lines as done for Spring?

Comment: not sure what you meant by log4j logs, spring uses log4j here. do you expect to print logs from log4j itself ? if so why do you want to do that?

Comment: I tried to do the way mentioned above but none of the logs are being logged into spring.log. Everything is still being logged to the common log file. Please advice if I am missing anything

Comment: Can some one please assist